# Locked out of Jenkins - removing config.xml doesn't fix

Tags: jenkins

I just messed up something in the configuration for Jenkins and now I cannot access it anymore. Whenever I login I get the error `cas is missing the Overall/Read permission`.

I already tried changing `config.xml` and removing `securityRealm` and `authorizationStrategy` and changing `useSecurity` to `false`. This didn't work so I figured I'd completely remove `config.xml`, this didn't work either.

Is there anything else I can do to get back in my Jenkins system?

Thanks!

EDIT: I restarted jenkins by using `service jenkins restart`

This is my Jenkins `config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson>
  <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
  <version>1.656</version>
  <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
  <disableSignup>false</disableSignup>
  <disableRememberMe>false</disableRememberMe>
  <projectNamingStrategy class="jenkins.model.ProjectNamingStrategy$DefaultProjectNamingStrategy"/>
  <workspaceDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace</workspaceDir>
  <buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>
  <markupFormatter class="hudson.markup.EscapedMarkupFormatter"/>
  <jdks/>
  <viewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultViewsTabBar"/>
  <myViewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultMyViewsTabBar"/>
  <clouds/>
  <quietPeriod>5</quietPeriod>
  <scmCheckoutRetryCount>0</scmCheckoutRetryCount>
  <views>
    <hudson.model.AllView>
      <owner class="hudson" reference="../../.."/>
      <name>All</name>
      <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
      <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
      <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
    </hudson.model.AllView>
  </views>
  <primaryView>All</primaryView>
  <slaveAgentPort>0</slaveAgentPort>
  <label></label>
  <crumbIssuer class="hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer">
    <excludeClientIPFromCrumb>false</excludeClientIPFromCrumb>
  </crumbIssuer>
  <nodeProperties/>
  <globalNodeProperties/>
</hudson>
```

Comment: Just want to make sure: you restarted the Jenkins service after making these changes right? sudo service jenkins restart

Comment: Yes, @edhurtig, I issued `service jenkins restart`

Comment: Huh, well that's interesting, should have worked if I remember correctly.  I might be forgetting about something important though :/

Comment: @edhurtig, do you know what the securityRealm and authorizationStrategy are for UNIX user login? Perhaps I can put that in my config and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was another hidden directory (`/var/usr/jenkins/.jenkins` for me) that contained another `config.xml`. Modifying this file actually propagated the changes I made.

I'm not sure what the use of `/var/usr/jenkins/config.xml` is, modifying it didn't seem to actually effect something unless there is a syntax error (In which case, it throws an exception)